# Excel - verify that all identical values in a column are in consecutive rows / Highlight or count non-consecutive duplicate values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to verify if all duplicate values in an Excel column are in consecutive rows or not.
I do not want to change the sort order of Excel. I just need to know whether there are duplicate values which are not in consecutive rows, as some of the processing I need to do relies on the assumption that all identical values will be in consecutive rows.

For example, if the values are like this:

```
John
John
Mary
Mary
John
Bob
Bob
Mary
```

I need to identify the John in the 5th row and Mary in the 8th row as non-consecutive duplicates, so that I can send the data back to the user and ask them to correct the data before I process it further.

Comment: Instead of verifying, why don't you sort the column?

Comment: The data is provided by business users. I do not want to change the sort order. I just have to inform the users to revalidate the data if there are non-consecutive duplicates, because it will indicate some data issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to identify them with a new column, using a relatively simple formula:

```
    =IF(AND(A2<>A1,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1),"non-consec dupe","ok")
```

It's counting the number of times that name appeared in the list from that point and above, and if it's more than one time AND the name above it is different, then flag as "non-consec dupe".

Or if you rather want to use a conditional formula to highlight the cell rather than add a new column, then use this as a conditional format formula in column A:

```
    =(AND(A2<>A1,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1))
```

[image]

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you take a look at this follow-up question: https://superuser.com/questions/1712956/excel-how-to-arrange-similar-values-right-after-the-1st-consecutive-block-of-ro