# Excel: How to arrange similar values right after the 1st consecutive block of rows containing the same value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet where values in a column are duplicate and in non-consecutive rows.
The values are not sorted in any particular order.

I want to bring all rows containing the same value together, but without using the Sort functionality. I want to bring the rows containing the next occurrences of a value, **immediately after the 1st consecutive block of rows containing that value**.

For example:
if original values are in this order:

```
1 John
2 John
3 Bob
4 Mary
5 Mary
6 John
7 Bob
8 Bob
9 Mary
10 Bob
```

I want the following:

```
1 John
2 John
6 John
3 Bob
7 Bob
8 Bob
10 Bob
4 Mary
5 Mary
9 Mary
```

Note that they are still not sorted in alphabetical order. I have moved the 2nd, 3rd and 4th occurrence of Bob to the row after the 1st Bob; I have moved the 3rd occurrence of John to the row after the 1st **consecutive block** of John, and so on.

What sequence of steps I should use to achieve the above outcome, without writing a macro? If it is not possible without a macro, then I am open to using a macro, but first preference is without using any macro.

Comment: You could create a custom sort list and sort on that.  Without VBA, in Excel 2016, you can create a list of distinct names (in the required order) using the Advanced Filter or with various formulas and helper columns.  But I think a VBA (or Power Query) routine would be easier for you to implement and maintain.

Comment: What will be the logic to create a custom sort list for this requirement? Can you give some ideas.

Comment: You create it by creating a distinct list of names.  In addition to the Advanced Filter, there are formula solutions you can search for on this and other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest would be to use Power Query.

- Select some cell in the table
- `Data` => `Get&Transform` => `Get Data` => `From Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens up:

  - Select the `Names` column
  - `Group by`

    - `operation: All Rows`
- Then merely expand the resultant column (which has tables) (by clicking on the double-headed arrow at the top of the column) selecting the "number" column only to be expanded
- You can reorder the columns if you want the number column first

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Does the Group By and subsequent expand, always guarantee the  resultant rows to be in predictable order?

Comment: @AllSolutions I've not seen it do otherwise, but I've not seen any documentation one way or the other.